# SetMethod in S4 - how to define a method that gets its argument from a pipelined function?

Tags: r, oop, pipeline, r-s4

I should implement an S4 code in R that gets the results on this query:

```
out <- subject (x, 14) %>% summary
```

I wrote my method for subject(x,14) and summary, too. The latter is an extension of the existing summary function, having as signature a class I defined.

The two functions work perfectly when entered separately. However, I am stuck figuring out how to pass the values of the first function as an input to the second, using the setMethod syntax required in S4.
Could any of you suggest a solution?

Here is my code:

```
    #Class definitions:
    setClass("LongitudinalData_S4", slots = c(DataFile = "data.frame"))
    setClass("Subject", slots= c(id = "numeric",value = "numeric",
                         timepoint = "numeric"), contains =       "LongitudinalData_S4") 
    setClass("Visit", slots = c(visit = "numeric"), contains = "Subject")
    setClass("Room", slots = c(room= "character"),contains = "Subject")

    #Set generics:
    setGeneric("summary")
    setGeneric(name="make_LD",def=function(x,...)
                   {standardGeneric("make_LD")
                   }
                   )
    setGeneric(name="SetDataFile", def=function(x,...)
                   {standardGeneric("SetDataFile")
                   }
                   )
    setGeneric(name="subject",def=function(s_ID,...)
                   {standardGeneric("subject")
                   }
                   )
    setGeneric(name="visit",def=function(v_ID, ...)
                   {standardGeneric("visit")
                   }
                   )
    setGeneric(name="room",def=function(r_name, ...)
                  {standardGeneric("room")
                  }
                  )
    #Set methods:
    setMethod(f="SetDataFile",signature="data.frame",definition=function(x)
                   {LD@DataFile<<-x
                   }
                   )
    setMethod(f="make_LD",signature="data.frame",definition=function(x)
                  {structure(list(data=x))
                   class<-"LongitudinalData_S4"
                   SetDataFile(data)
                   return(data)
                  }
                  )
    setMethod("[",  signature(x="LongitudinalData_S4",i="ANY"), definition=function(x, i)
      {f<-x@id[which(x@id==i)]
       return(d<-f[1])
      }
      )
    setMethod(summary, signature(x="numeric", y="character"), function(x,y)
      {baba<<-subset(LD@DataFile, LD@DataFile[[y]]==x)
      class(baba)=="data.frame"
      f<-(with(baba, tapply(value, list(visit, room), FUN=mean)))
      return(print(f))
      }
      )

     setMethod(subject,"numeric", definition = function(s_ID)
     {if(!(s_ID %in% LD_Subject@id))
      {cat("No such ID in the dataframe.")}
      else
      { cat(sprintf("Subject ID: %d",LD_Subject[s_ID], "\n"))
        cat("   ", "\n")
      }
     }
     )

    #Create objects:
    LD<-new("LongitudinalData_S4")
    LD_Visit <-new("Visit", visit = data$visit)
    LD_Room <-new("Room", room = as.character(data$room))
    LD_Subject <-new("Subject", id = data$ID, value =data$value, timepoint = data$timepoint)
```

By calling subject(14), I get the result I expect:

```
    > subject(14)
    Subject ID: 14
```

By calling summary(14, „ID”), I get the result I expect as well:

```
    > summary(14, "ID")
   bedroom den dining room family  room hall kitchen living room office study room tv room
    0 NA  4.786592  NA          NA           NA   NA      NA     2.75000     NA         NA      NA
    1 NA  3.401442  NA          NA     8.426549   NA      NA          NA     NA         NA      NA
    2 NA 18.583635  NA          NA           NA   NA      NA    22.55069     NA         NA      NA
```

However, what I should have is the above result, by calling subject(14) %>% summary. Here I am stuck finding a way.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example. Otherwise it is very hard to give an answer.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, now I edited my question so that it contains code as well. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: In your current implementation you implement a method for the generic summary where (x, y) are (numeric, character). I think this definition in itself is a bit ambitious. You probably should implement a method with a signature which is more specific to your scenario and avoid the use of only atomics in your method signatures. I suppose you can solve your initial problem by defining a the summary method for the type 'subject'. And I think your function 'subject' should really be a constructor, returning an object of this type (at the moment it looks like a show method).

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian. Provided that both summary and subject methods worked more efficiently and without ambiguity, do you think that I would still had to write a separate method for the pipeline function (%>%), or it should take care of the chain of function without any further coding?

Comment: Yes, when you define your function subject, so that it returns an object of type 'subject' and furthermore you define a method for 'summary' which consumes an object of type 'subject', the pipe operator can handle the rest. After all, it is just syntactic sugar for `summary(subject(x, 14))`. At the moment your method 'subject' returns the value NULL and only makes sense because of its side-effects, i.e. printing into the console. However, printing into the console should be handled in a method for the generic 'show' (see `?show` for details).

Comment: @Sebastian: I really appreciate your support in this matter. Yes, I will still have to correct my methods. Knowing that once I am done with that the pipelining should take care of itself - this is kind of a relief :) Thank you!